# @Async working without @EnableAsync in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm writing tests for my Async method, annotated with @Async. I'm trying to disable Async by using below configuration class:

```
@Profile("!integ-test")
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration {}
```

Calling code:

```
@Autowired private ApiDelegate apiDelegate;

apiDelegate.exportResources(searchContext);
```

Method:

```
 @Async
 public void exportResources(
  SearchContext searchContext,
  ) {}
```

Spring boot version: 2.3.12.RELEASE

The problem is the method is still being executed asynchronously. There is no place else where @EnableAsync is placed. I've also tried removing @EnableAsync altogether, but the method remains asynchronous. There seems to be no effect of removing @EnableAsync.
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please show how you are executing the code as well as specifying which Spring Boot version you are using. Are you by any chance using `spring-boot-starter-actuator` as that will enable asyn and scheduling by default.

Comment: @M.Deinum Updated my question

Comment: Yes, I have `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator` in dependencies.

Comment: Well if you have that async and scheduling is enabled by default as that is needed by actuator.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum. Is there any way I can override that behaviour?

Comment: How do you know that it's being executed asynchronously? Are you sure you run your code with profile "integ-test" enabled?

Comment: Yes, I have "integ-test" profile active. Have debugged the test to identify the method is being executed asynchronously @dekkard

Comment: @M.Deinum do you have any links  with the info on `spring-boot-starter-actuator` activating async processing? Just tried to repro this in an empty Spring boot 2.6 project and an `@Async` method is executed in the same thread as a caller if `@EnableAsync` is not specified in a configuration.

Comment: If you don't use the actuator it won't enable it. It might depend on which exporter you use for exposing your metrics.